# Fix size of stackview to all screen sizes

Tags: swift

I have a stackview like this

[image]

I pinned the stackview like this:

```
Top: 200, Leading: 20, Trailing: 20, Bottom: 200
```

I want the stackview to be fixed to this size for every screen size, how do I achieve this?

Comment: But which size? Here you are not giving any size. If you want to remove your constraints and add center horizontally / vertically constraints and then width / height constraints with the desired size.

Comment: I'd like it to be size 500x500

Comment: @BorisGrunwald For all devices 500X500 or you want to display it 1:1 according to device width?

Comment: No sorry 1:1 according to device width

Comment: you should use two of them ( top or bottom ) with (leading or trailing) and after that add width and height or one of them with aspect ratio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose the Stack View and add Aspect Ration :

[image]

Then double click on the Aspect Ration around the Stack View and make the Multiplier 1:1 :

[image]

Then you can add Trailing and Leading constrains + Center Vertically in Safe Area.

Answer (score 2):

**Add leading, trailing, center vertically and aspect ratio 1:1 constraint to main StakeView.**

[image]

Also, Add **equal widths** and **equal heights** constraint to each button.

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: center horizontally isn't' needed as you've added leading and trailing